# What is enableEventScheduler in ActivitiesSettings

Tags: metadata

When fetching the `ActivitiesSettings` metadata from a production org or a full sandbox of the org, it contains a boolean value, `enableEventScheduler`:

```
<enableEventScheduler>false</enableEventScheduler>
```

When trying to deploy the `ActivitiesSettings` metadata containing this element to a Developer Pro sandbox of the same production org, I get an error:

```
Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}enableEventScheduler invalid at this location in type ActivitiesSettings
```

If I retrieve `ActivitiesSettings` from this dev sandbox, it doesn't include the `enableEventScheduler` element.

The [documentation for ActivitiesSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_activitiessettings.htm) doesn't include the `enableEventScheduler` element.

What is `enableEventScheduler`?